# Update column values in a group based on one row in that group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe from source data that resembles the following:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'test_group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
         'test_type': [np.nan,'memory', np.nan, np.nan, 'visual', np.nan, np.nan,
         'auditory', np.nan]}
Out[1]:
   test_group test_type
0           1       NaN
1           1    memory
2           1       NaN
3           2       NaN
4           2    visual
5           2       NaN
6           3       NaN
7           3  auditory
8           3       NaN
```

`test_group` represents the grouping of the rows, which represent a test. I need to replace the NaNs in column `test_type` in each `test_group` with the value of the row that is not a NaN, e.g. memory, visual, etc.

I've tried a variety of approaches including isolating the "real" value in `test_type` such as

```
In [4]: df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].unique()
Out[4]:
test_group
1      [nan, memory]
2      [nan, visual]
3    [nan, auditory]
```

Easy enough, I can index into each row and pluck out the value I want. This seems to head in the right direction:

```
In [6]: df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].unique().apply(lambda x: x[1])
Out[6]:
test_group
1      memory
2      visual
3    auditory
```

I tried this among many other things but it doesn't quite work (note: apply and transform give the same result):

```
In [15]: grp = df.groupby('test_group')
In [16]: df['test_type'] = grp['test_type'].unique().transform(lambda x: x[1])

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   test_group test_type
0           1       NaN
1           1    memory
2           1    visual
3           2  auditory
4           2       NaN
5           2       NaN
6           3       NaN
7           3       NaN
8           3       NaN
```

I'm sure if I looped it I'd be done with things, but loops are too slow as the data set is millions of records per file.

Comment: `df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].bfill().ffill()`? What is your expected output?

Comment: Is it always that initially, every group has only one valid value and the rest of the values in each group are NaN?

Comment: @It_is_Chris - yes, that gets it done. Thanks!

Comment: @Ch3steR - correct.

Comment: @schwim Thank you for the clarification. That invariant helped me find a faster solution than dual fillna.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that there's a unique non-nan value per group, the following should satisfy your request.

```
>>> df['test_type'] = df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].ffill().bfill() 
>>> df
   test_group test_type
0           1    memory
1           1    memory
2           1    memory
3           2    visual
4           2    visual
5           2    visual
6           3  auditory
7           3  auditory
8           3  auditory
```

edit:

The original answer used

```
df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

but it looks like according to [schwim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5401841/schwim)'s timings `ffill`/`bfill` is significantly faster (for some reason).

Comment: Per a prior comment [this](https://gist.github.com/gschwim/2a069fcce38277bfa462571debeb90f0) compares the performance of the 3 methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`GroupBy.size`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to get the size of each group. Then [*boolean index*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) using [**`Series.isna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html). Now, use [**`Index.repeat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [**`df.reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
repeats = df.groupby('test_group').size()
out = df[~df['test_type'].isna()]
out.reindex(out.index.repeat(repeats)).reset_index(drop=True)

   test_group test_type
0           1    memory
1           1    memory
2           1    memory
3           2    visual
4           2    visual
5           2    visual
6           3  auditory
7           3  auditory
8           3  auditory
```

---

#### timeit analysis:

*Benchmarking dataframe*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test_group': [1]*10_001 + [2]*10_001 + [3]*10_001, 
                            'test_type' : [np.nan]*10_000 + ['memory'] +
                                          [np.nan]*10_000 + ['visual'] +
                                          [np.nan]*10_000 + ['auditory']})   
df.shape
# (30003, 2)
```

---

Results:

```
# Ch3steR's answer
In [54]: %%timeit 
    ...: repeats = df.groupby('test_group').size() 
    ...: out = df[~df['test_type'].isna()] 
    ...: out.reindex(out.index.repeat(repeats)).reset_index(drop=True) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
2.56 ms ± 73.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# timgeb's answer
In [55]: %%timeit 
    ...: df['test_type'] = df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill') 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                                 
10.1 ms ± 724 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Almost ~4X faster. I believe it's because boolean indexing is very fast. And reindex + repeat is lightwieght compared to dual fillna.

Comment: NB: If you are running timeit test, please run my answer first as it doesn't mutate the original dataframe, while Tim's soln mutates the original dataframe. Non-mutating version of Tim's would be using [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) `df.assign(test_type = df.groupby('test_group')['test_type'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))`

Comment: I ran both approaches through their paces. I noticed your df creation doesn't quite match the pattern I have here. Regardless, both approaches appear to work fine. I modified the df to be just about 300k lines of pattern that matches my data, and indeed your approach is significantly faster. Oddly, it isn't faster on my actual data set. I'll need to figure out why - the patterns and columns of interest are the same, my prod data just has more columns. Hmm.

Comment: Ah, I found it.

Comment: When I implemented tim's approach to it, i ended up modifying it to use .ffill().bfill() rather than .fillna(method=...). This approach does appear to be faster still. With 299997 rows:
@Ch3steR method: 46.3 ms ± 953 µs per loop
ffill().bfill() method: 34.3 ms ± 2.04 ms per loop
Tim method: 22.9 s ± 430 ms per loop!
I repeated several times to be sure.

Comment: @schwim interesting and unexpected.

Comment: good answer. any reason you're using `reindex` over `loc`?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you, no particular reason but I frequently use reindex with repeat might just be a force of habit. I have measured the performance comparing the both there's little to no difference. But yeah `.loc` is less typing.

Comment: I put a quick comparison [here](https://gist.github.com/gschwim/2a069fcce38277bfa462571debeb90f0)
Worth noting is if I drop the extra columns, @Ch3steR method is slightly faster.